# Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried crawling a specific site using selenium and webdriver_manager.chrome, and my code crawled elements of that site totally. But after crawling, the following error message appears in the console window.

`ERROR:gpu_init.cc(426) Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled`

When I first found it, I unchecked Hardware hardware accleration of chrome also it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Is this a show stopper for you ?

Comment: @cruisepandey yes. when that message came out, then I couldn't using a console

Comment: I've been using Selenium with Chromedriver for several years. This issue has occurred from just a few months ago. It seems like the Chromedriver v.89 with `headless` option is the cause of this problem \[[1](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/n6qywt/hardware_acceleration_fail_in_chrome_on_linux/), [2](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/telemetry/c/bEgV1EH63eA)\].

Comment: @Hoinobert how are you manipulating the webdriver chromeoptions?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Tested environment**

Windows OS, Chromedriver vesion 89, headless mode

**Solution**

I am not certain that this can be a solution for your question, since the error message is slightly different.

As I remember correctly, the error message `Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader` has been shown after the Chromedriver version 89 as a bug (but not certain) [1].

In case of Windows, `--headless` and `--disable-gpu` options are required to make the chromedriver work as a headless mode [2]. It seems like `--disable-gpu` is also required for Linux because of the bug [3].

1. The error message does not appear if both `--headless` and `--disable-gpu` options are removed. However, the chromedriver does not work as a headless mode anymore.
2. In my case, the error message does not affect the operation of a headless chrome. As I found, "Normally, Chrome would just fall back to work without GPU. However, for consistent results, Telemetry requires the presence of GPU [4]."
3. I've additionally applied `--disable-software-rasterizer` option to disable WebGL [5]. The error message does not show anymore under the headless operation.

**References**

[1] https://reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/n6qywt/hardware_acceleration_fail_in_chrome_on_linux/
[2] https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome
[3] https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678
[4] https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/telemetry/c/bEgV1EH63eA
[5] https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617551

Comment: `--disable-software-rasterizer` solved it for me; thanks for the detailed answer

Comment: how to enforce acceleration? coz rendering is slow for 3d canvas

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem with selenium and chromedriver. For me the solution was to activate WebGL in Chrome browser. I did the following

1. `chrome://settings` -> Click `Advanced` at the bottom -> Check the `Use hardware acceleration when available` box

[image]

2. `chrome://flags` -> Search for `WebGL` in the search bar -> Enable / Activate WebGL
   [image]

There are much better instructions here: https://superuser.com/questions/836832/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-my-browser

Comment: Indeed, disabling hardware acceletarion did take care of that, but it only happened because Chrome was updated and I think, it reset this option as it was woking one day, and next, not.

Comment: Thanks, already had the hardware acceleration setting, but enable webgl solved the issue for me, also had problems to get the developer tools to show, but that seem solved now. Doing electron development so not sure how I would have pased parameters as suggested in accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

This warning was being shown to me in a setup where chromium was running through Xvfb. I managed to get rid of this warning by adding the following flag to the command line:

```
--disable-features=DefaultPassthroughCommandDecoder
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error as a result of using NVIDIA's Quadro view so for me the fix was to disable that.

Answer (score 1):

I received this error during Eclipse Startup and fixed it by changing two things:

1. Now using a more recent Java VM for Eclipse, in my case I was moving from Java8 to Java11
2. Also moving from JRE to JDK

Add Eclipse Start Parameter:

```
-vm C:\PROGRA~1\ECLIPS~1\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin\javaw.exe
```

Answer (score -2):

there should be typo mistake in your code , please check ,

### i got the similar error in electron

```js
[7608:1220/032708.152:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(523)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

the problem was type mistake

before

> wrong code

```js
// events funstions of electron
SM_app.on('redy', F_create_windows);
```

> fixed code

```js
// events funstions of electron
SM_app.on('ready', F_create_windows);
```

i was missing `a` in my code. `redy`

## Check Your Code. Again