# Getting a Passthrough is not supported GL is disabled, even though it is enabled; unable to run web scraping python script

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Using Chrome and ChromeDriver to run a python script to web scrape. The script runs and I can see that it is querying the website, but once it is done it fails. The script ended up creating the CSV file, but it is empty with no web scraping data.

Keep getting a passthrough is not supported GL disabled, even though I enabled it.
I used the following stack overflow steps to make sure the GL enabled: [second stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501093/passthrough-is-not-supported-gl-is-disabled). WebGL didn't exist as an option to enable so I enabled WebGL Draft Extensions instead.  Along with the Passthrough error...intermittently gets handshake error.

I have made sure my Chrome Driver and Chrome are the same versions. I have installed an older version of Chrome with an older version of Chrome Driver, and that didn't work. Don't know what else to try.

Comment: I am having EXACTLY the same problem, including the bit about Draft Extensions. Bookmarking this so that if I figure it out I can come give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a project using Selenium wherein my program iterates through all the elements(images) of a website and downloads them simultaneously. Everything was working fine but on the same website at a particular search query, the program wasn't working fine. It used to stuck every time whenever it encounters a particular element and the same error `Passthrough is not supported GL is disabled, Angle is` used to come. I tried the solution provided in another stack overflow question but didn't worked. After following many approaches, I ended up with this solution:-

```
header = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/97.0.4692.71'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=header)
```

The problem actually was occurring in the `request.get()` method.

**Fix**

Just create a dictionary as created above and add your "browserName/version" in it rest is pretty much clear to you.

I hope it will work for you as well.