# Chrome/Chromium --headless cannot create Pref Service with no user dir

Tags: google-chrome, server, debian, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to use chrome/chromium headless on a debian server with no GUI. Everytime I try to use it I get the following errro regardless wether I'm logged in as root or as a non-root user.

[image: Chromium headless error: Cannot create Pref Service]

How do I start chromium headless for the first time? Why can it not find the user data dir? I've also tried specifying the user data dir with `--user-data-dir` to no avail.

Comment: This is a duplicate with **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501093/passthrough-is-not-supported-gl-is-disabled**

Comment: It's not a duplicate to this question since my question is focusing on the `cannot create Pref Service` part. I don't really care for the passthrough part.

Comment: This is just a warning, this is not the not working cause