# Android FFMPEG Compilation error: gpu_init.cc(454)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is

Tags: shell, opencv, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg

I came here to ask the experts. I'm working on an Android app that needs to capture camera preview frames from the NDK, for that I want to use OpenCV's `VideoCapture` (I properly integrated OpenCV with the NDK). The problem is that OpenCV's `VideoCapture` wont work on Android NDK since it has no backend, (Unable to read videos and start camera preview, `VideoCapture.open(...)` returns always `false`). So here I decided to use FFMPEG as the backend for capturing videos with OpenCV.
I searched the web and found many tutorials that explain how to integrate FFMPEG with Android NDK, and I followed every one of them. The problem is that all what I've tried so far brought me to the same place, in which I get stuck with an error that completely blocks the entire process.

**More Details:**

I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@donturner/using-ffmpeg-for-faster-audio-decoding-967894e94e71) for compiling FFMPEG for Android.

In order to build FFMPEG (before the part of linking it with Android NDK), I have to run a shell script that compiles the libraries to be linked with the project. When i just run the script i get this error:

`[1268:0414/153141.454:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(454)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is`

I searched the web about it and found many suggestions, most of them like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501093/passthrough-is-not-supported-gl-is-disabled) suggest to enable WebGL. I checked it and made sure WebGL is enabled across all web browsers. But the error persists.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**build_script.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$ANDROID_NDK" ]; then
  echo "Please set ANDROID_NDK to the Android NDK folder"
  exit 1
fi

#Change to your local machine's architecture
HOST_OS_ARCH=windows-x86_64

function configure_ffmpeg {

  ABI=$1
  PLATFORM_VERSION=$2
  TOOLCHAIN_PATH=$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/${HOST_OS_ARCH}/bin
  local STRIP_COMMAND

  # Determine the architecture specific options to use
  case ${ABI} in
  armeabi-v7a)
    TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=armv7a-linux-androideabi
    STRIP_COMMAND=arm-linux-androideabi-strip
    ARCH=armv7-a
    ;;
  arm64-v8a)
    TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=aarch64-linux-android
    ARCH=aarch64
    ;;
  x86)
    TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=i686-linux-android
    ARCH=x86
    EXTRA_CONFIG="--disable-asm"
    ;;
  x86_64)
    TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=x86_64-linux-android
    ARCH=x86_64
    EXTRA_CONFIG="--disable-asm"
    ;;
  esac

  if [ -z ${STRIP_COMMAND} ]; then
    STRIP_COMMAND=${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-strip
  fi

  echo "Configuring FFmpeg build for ${ABI}"
  echo "Toolchain path ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}"
  echo "Command prefix ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}"
  echo "Strip command ${STRIP_COMMAND}"

  ./configure \
  --prefix=build/${ABI} \ # The path where the resulting libraries and headers will be installed after `make install` is run. The resulting directory structure is "build/{armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64}/{include, lib}".
  --target-os=android \ # Target operating system name.
  --arch=${ARCH} \ # Target CPU architecture e.g. armv7-a.
  --enable-cross-compile \ # We are compiling for a different target architecture than the host.
  --cc=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}${PLATFORM_VERSION}-clang \ # Path to the C compiler. In our case we're using clang. 
  --strip=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${STRIP_COMMAND} \ # Path to the strip binary for our target architecture.
  --enable-small \ # Optimize for size instead of speed.
  --disable-programs \ # Do not build command line programs. We don't need them as our app will be interacting with the FFmpeg API. 
  --disable-doc \ # Do not build documentation.
  --enable-shared \ # Build shared libraries. We'll keep the FFmpeg .so files separate from our main shared library.
  --disable-static \ # Do not build static libraries.
  ${EXTRA_CONFIG} \
  --disable-everything \ # Disable all modules. To keep the library size to a minimum we will explicitly specify the modules to be built below.
  --enable-decoder=mp3 \ # Enable the MP3 decoder. For a list of supported decoders type ./configure --help.
  --enable-demuxer=mp3 # Enable the MP3 demuxer. For a list of supported demuxers type ./configure --help.

  return $?
}

function build_ffmpeg {

  configure_ffmpeg $1 $2

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
          make clean
          make -j12
          make install
  else
          echo "FFmpeg configuration failed, please check the error log."
  fi
}

build_ffmpeg armeabi-v7a 16
build_ffmpeg arm64-v8a 21
build_ffmpeg x86 16
build_ffmpeg x86_64 21
```

I searched the entire web for a solution, but found that no one is talking about this error in the context of integrating FFMPEG with android, so I've no idea how to solve this problem. Am I missing something or what?

**Versions:**

Android studio 4.0.0
OpenCV 4.0.1
Windows 10 (x86_64)
Cloned the latest FFMPEG source code by running command `git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git` under `D:\Develop`.

Thanks for reading this question so far, helpful ideas will be warmly welcomed.

Comment: Have you looked into [`ffmpeg-android-maker` project](https://github.com/Javernaut/ffmpeg-android-maker)? I found it linked from FFmpeg Wiki and is still active. The repo owner also has a few Medium posts relating to it. (The issue appears to be related to including necessarily hardware components, but that's beyond anything I know much of.)

Comment: @kesh Nice explanation, but the error is still there.